# PHP sorting array output

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

UPDATE 2 (Players Handicap Index Calculation)

```
    $sql3 = "SELECT roundID FROM rounds WHERE userID='$userID'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rounds = mysql_num_rows($result3);


    //CALCULATE USER HANDICAP INDEX IF TOTAL_ROUNDS > 4
    if($total_rounds > 4){              
        if($total_rounds<7) { $score_count = 1; }
        elseif($total_rounds<9) { $score_count = 2; }
        elseif($total_rounds<11) { $score_count = 3; }
        elseif($total_rounds<13) { $score_count = 4; }
        elseif($total_rounds<15) { $score_count = 5; }
        elseif($total_rounds<17) { $score_count = 6; }
        elseif($total_rounds<18) { $score_count = 7; }
        elseif($total_rounds<19) { $score_count = 8; }
        elseif($total_rounds<20) { $score_count = 9; }
        else { $score_count = 10; }

        $sql2 = "SELECT differential FROM rounds WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

        $diff_results = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
            $diff_results[] = $row['differential'];
        }

        sort($diff_results);

        $diff_results = array_slice($diff_results, 0, $score_count);

        $handicapIndex = array_sum($diff_results) / $score_count * 0.96;
        $handicapIndex = (floor($handicapIndex * 10)) / 10;
```

Hopefully this will give you all and idea of how I calculate a players handicap index. Now I would like to show the player (user) the rounds (date ordered) that are used to calculate his index.

Always appreciative!

**UPDATE (structure of rounds table)**

```
    roundID - auto incrementing primary key
    userID - INT
    courseID - INT
    tee - VARCHAR
    differential - FLOAT
    date - DATE
```

I am struggling to even get started with this feature I am trying to implement.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a set of mysql db results I would like to sort by field differential.  I pull them out of the db like this:

```
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM rounds WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20";
    $result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rounds = mysql_num_rows($result4);
```

As you can see above I counted the rows returned to run through this if-elseif-else statement to figure out how many scores I need to highlight with different css:

```
    if($total_rounds<7) { $score_count = 1; }
    elseif($total_rounds<9) { $score_count = 2; }
    elseif($total_rounds<11) { $score_count = 3; }
    elseif($total_rounds<13) { $score_count = 4; }
    elseif($total_rounds<15) { $score_count = 5; }
    elseif($total_rounds<17) { $score_count = 6; }
    elseif($total_rounds<18) { $score_count = 7; }
    elseif($total_rounds<19) { $score_count = 8; }
    elseif($total_rounds<20) { $score_count = 9; }
    else { $score_count = 10; }
```

For example, if $total_rounds = 16 my $score_count would be 6.
Now I need to take this data set of 16 rows and spit it out with php so I maintain my ORDER BY date while applying a different css format to the 6 figured in the above if-elseif-else statement. The $score_count is figured because I need to highlight (aka apply different css) to the 6 lowest scores of the 16 row data set WHILE maintaining my date order.

The desired output would look like this (with the * denoting the separate css format *).

01-08-2013 - 16

01-07-2012 - 1 *

01-06-2013 - 15

01-05-2012 - 2 *

01-04-2013 - 14

01-03-2012 - 3 *

01-02-2013 - 13

01-01-2012 - 4 *

12-31-2012 - 12

12-30-2012 - 5 *

12-29-2012 - 11

12-28-2012 - 6 *

12-27-2012 - 10

12-26-2012 - 9

12-25-2012 - 8

12-24-2012 - 7

Please let me know if you have questions.

Thanks

Comment: your desired output is not ordered by date, but you describe that you want it to be?

Comment: please show structure of rounds table

Comment: @Bhavik - UPDATED with rounds table structure above will this suffice?

Comment: what will be the score? I dont understand which column's data you are considering as score

Comment: @Bhavik, the score would be the differential column, good question.

Comment: can two dates have same score(differential)? I mean, can two dates have score of 5(eg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of steps that you will have to follow.

1) Sort the results with score(differential) and get the ids of the six records having lowest score.

```
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM rounds WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY differential LIMIT 20";
$result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
$total_rounds = mysql_num_rows($result4);

if($total_rounds<7) { $score_count = 1; }
elseif($total_rounds<9) { $score_count = 2; }
elseif($total_rounds<11) { $score_count = 3; }
elseif($total_rounds<13) { $score_count = 4; }
elseif($total_rounds<15) { $score_count = 5; }
elseif($total_rounds<17) { $score_count = 6; }
elseif($total_rounds<18) { $score_count = 7; }
elseif($total_rounds<19) { $score_count = 8; }
elseif($total_rounds<20) { $score_count = 9; }
else { $score_count = 10; }

$idsArray = array();
for($i=0; $i<$score_count; $i++){
    $dets = mysql_fetch_array($result4);
    $idsArray[] = $dets['roundID'];
}
```

2) Loop over records and match the id in array that you have made by first step. If id matches apply CSS otherwise not.

```
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM rounds WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20";
$result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());

while($dets = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
    if(in_array($dets['roundID'], $idsArray)){
        //apply CSS
        //display details here
    }
    else{
        //display details here
    }
}
```

Note: You should stop using mysql_* now. Its highly recommended by experts to use mysqli_* instead

Comment: this is it, makes complete sense. Thanks for your diligent work and quick response. Marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I will take your example of `$total_rounds = 16` my `$score_count would be 6`.

```
$total_rounds = 16;
$score_count = 6 // comes from the if-else loop you already have

// now we loop over the result
// the css is applied to every odd result, until $score_count is not 0

$counter = 0;
while( ( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result4 ) ) !== false ) {
    if( ( $counter % 2 ) && $score_count ) {
        echo $data['date']; // apply your css here
    } else {
        echo $data['date'];
    }
    $counter++;
    $score_count--;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks its a start but the highlighted row may not always be the odd numbers as I showed in my desired output. That was stupid of me, I should have mixed it up, I only did that for ease of computation in my mind. Any further thoughts?

Comment: btw, what if two dates has same score? This is also possible. Isnt it?

Comment: @BillChambers hmm..but you can't just go highlighting _any_ row at will. There must be a logic according to which the rows are highlighted. Please tell us that condition.(Some filters)

Comment: Yes that is also possible if one plays two rounds of golf in the same day, which can happen.

Comment: @Pushpesh, the logic, trying to be as clear as possible is, SELECT the latest rounds (max 20), run total rounds through if-elseif-else statement to figure out the number of THE LOWEST DIFFERENTIALS in which to highlight in my date ordered output.

Comment: For example, if I have 16 rounds entered as in my example above that would mean I need to select the 6 LOWEST DIFFERENTIALS of that 16 round result set and spit out ALL 16 rounds (date ordered) with the 6 six lowest rounds highlighted in the output.

Comment: @Pushpesh and Bhavik, I'll update again shortly with some logic I use to calculate a players handicap index, I think this will give you an idea of how I am using this formula.